# Editing a word in a sty file

Tags: packages, patching, definition

I want to edit a word in a .sty file. I'm learning Latex and I don't know if it can be edited by using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands in the preamble.

The .sty file (`novel-PostLayout`, from the `novel` class) has the following code:

```
%% LABEL DRAFT OPTION
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Writes DRAFT inside upper left of TrimBox, when in draft mode.
% This macro must go here, in order, so that the label is not over-shaded.
\ifdraftdoc
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \@getPageXY%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
      \raisebox{-\@SetFontSize}{\textbf{~DRAFT}}%
    }%
  }%
\fi
%% end label draft.
```

I want to change the word `~DRAFT` for another. My problem is edit that code in `\ifdraftdoc`. When it is `\newcommand`, I can use `\renewcommand`, but I don't know if the conditional has something similar.

Is it possible to edit it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which `.sty` file is it?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik [Here](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/luatex/latex/novel/novel-PostLayout.sty) you can see the sty file. This is a package from [novel](https://ctan.org/pkg/novel) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one's trickier to change because this doesn't immediately look to be in any definition. You have to hack a bit to find where that code is stored. The macro `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` adds its argument to `\ESO@HookIBG`, so you can use `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to change the text. It has to be done `\AtEndPreamble` because that's when `novel-PostLayout` is loaded:

```latex
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \patchcmd\ESO@HookIBG
    {DRAFT}{Something else}{}{}}
\makeatother
```

Compilable code:

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{novel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \patchcmd\ESO@HookIBG
    {DRAFT}{Something else}{}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works perfect!

Comment: @Cantón Glad it helped. You can mark the question as solved by clicking the checkmark to the left

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was searching it. I have to learn how to use this page too. It is very good.

Comment: @Cantón No problem :-) Welcome again!